# What local IP would you be given if all are in use?

Tags: networking, ip

**This questions is *hypothetical*, this situation would most likely never happen nor could any router handle it**

### Situation 1

Lets say for example you (somehow) managed to put 255 devices onto your network. Lets refer to the 255th device as D255 and, just for later reference, the router's IP address is 192.168.0.1. If I am correct D255's local IP address should be 192.168.1.255. So what if we buy a new device (D256) and connect it to my home internet along with the other 255 devices. What would D256's local IP address become? I thought about it and I assume that it would be 192.168.2.1. Am I correct?

### Situation 2

After thinking about situation 1 I came up with another situation. What if you had 65025 (255 * 255 = 65025, if you see where I'm going with this.) devices connected to the your internet? The last device's (I will refer to as D65025) local IP adress should be 192.168.255.255 (That is assuming that situation1's solution is correct.). So what if I go out and buy a another device (D65026) what would it's local IP address be? It can't become 192.168.256.1 because the numbers can not exceed 255 and it can't become 192.169.1.1 because 192.168.x.x is the local IP reserve and 192.169.1.1 exceeds the local IP limit and (correct me if I'm wrong) would be a external IP address. So what would happen?

**I appreciate your feedback!**

Comment: The DHCP server will either not lease you an IP address at all, or it will release another one whose lease has expired and lease you that one.

Comment: Why do you want to know?

Comment: Curiosity, as all hypothetical questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A local network will typically be configured with a DHCP server to hand out IPv4 address leases along with name server addresses and a gateway address.

Residential and small commercial routers are usually configured to do Network Address Translation and have a DHCP server configured to hand out Private IPv4 addresses and the router's private IP as the gateway and nameserver. The size of the local subnet is determined by the router's configuration.

A typical configuration is `192.168.0.0/24` which provides 254 host addresses.

The DHCP server has configuration that specifies the address pool it can hand out leases for, how a DHCP server behaves if it is asked for a lease when all addresses in the pool are currently assigned depends on the configuration, but in most situations it will just not respond as there are "no free leases".

In this situation a host will likely select a link-local [zero-configuration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking) address from `169.254.0.0/16` and not have any Internet access or any other hosts on the network except those with Zero Conf addresses. It may retry DHCP at a later point.

The [RFC1918](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918#page-4) private address block `192.168.0.0/16` actually has capacity for 65534 uniquely addressed hosts. Ignoring the issues of having a layer 2 broadcast domain of this size, the same constraints apply: when there are no leases left to assign, none are assigned.

If these private addresses are to have Internet access they will be Network Address Translated to one or more public IP addresses (usually one) by the router. One public address is unlikely to be sufficient for a large number of private network hosts, constrained by the availability of local TCP / UDP port numbers.

I suggest you read up on IP networking to fill in basic knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using DHCP, when you run out of addresses, it will kick one of the other devices off the network, probably the one which connected first. There are only so many devices which can connect to a network, but that number depends on the router configuration.

Comment: Could you elaborate more? Like what if you're not using DHCP? Also what about both situations? Would both cause a device to get kicked off?

Comment: This is not a programming question.  As such it should be flagged/voted to be closed, not answered.

Comment: @NitrousOxide If you're not using DHCP your question has no meaning. You would allocate the IP address yourself statically, and you would see that there are none left, and what happened next would be up to you.

Comment: @NathanOliver True, surely it could be migrated though.

Comment: Oh, I apologize for that, I was another question about IP addresses here so I assumed that this was the correct site. Also, I don't know what DHCP is, I assumed that there would be another option.

Comment: @NitrousOxide DHCP is the mechanism that assigns IP addresses, which is what you're asking about. If you don't know that, it's hard to see why you're even asking the question. There is another option. Doing it yourself manually. In which case only you know what you would do when you run out of addresses.